# What is the difference between string.split and strings.split

Tags: .net, vb.net, split

There are three functions for splitting a string in .net by a delimiter, String.Split and Strings.Split (from the Microsoft.VisualBasic dll) and of course Regex.Split which uses patterns.

What is the difference between String.Split and Strings.Split?

Comment: And yet you don't mention any Basic functions. `String.Split` is the same as the Visual Basic `Split` **function**.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is Strings.Split takes a **string** while String.Split takes an array (param array actually) of **characters**. Which splits on any of the characters in the array.

String.Split should be used when you need to split on one or more characters or when you know there will be a single delimiter, but don’t know which one it will be (comma, tab, or space).  It is the most common and will cover most cases.

Strings.Split should be used when you need to split on a specific word.

Regex.Split should of course be used when you need to split on a pattern, not a fixed character or word.  It **can** be used to split on a specific word, but will probably be slower than Strings.Split (but Strings.Split may be excluded by team policy as some people don’t like the MS.VisualBasic namespace)

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split` should never be used. It's a holdover from VB6 and such functions should not be used unless they add actual value, which `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split` doesn't. `System.String.Split` is overloaded and allows you to split on one or more characters or substrings, plus it provides other options too.